# Can't access stdObject array using [] or -> operators

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `stdObject` and its `var_dump` result is below:

```
var_dump($name)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#853 (2) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(2) "John"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(8) "Smith"
  }
}
```

I am trying to make a new variable `$fullname` by using `$name['firstname].$name['lastname']`. It doesn't work, gives the error `Undefined index`

Then I tried using the `->` operator on `$name->firstname + $name->lastname`. Gives the error: `trying to get property of non-object`

How do I go about this?

Comment: `$name[0]->firstname . $name[0]->lastname;`. PHP version dependent.

Comment: Make this an answer, and explain it as well please. Thanks

Comment: use $obj = current($name); $obj->lastname etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$name[0]->firstname . $name[0]->lastname;`

Basically you were trying to access an array as an object. You can see from your `var_dump` that the variable contains an array. That array contains an object with 2 properties. So `$name[0]` gives you the object, and `->firstname` accesses the `firstname` property of that object.

Comment: It's PHP 5.6. Could you please explain what I was doing wrong? A newbie here.

Comment: @omrakhur: this is not version issue, your object is inside the 0 index

Comment: Basically you were trying to access an array as an object. You can see from your `var_dump` that the variable contains an array. That array contains and object with 2 properties. So `$name[0]` gives you the object, and `->firstname` accesses the `firstname` property of that object. Make sense?

Comment: (Added comment to answer).

Comment: @JonStirling cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$name[0]['firstname].$name[0]['lastname'];
```

As the $name contains

> array(1)

in it.

**Explanation:** $name is an array of objects. So to access its value you have to use index as well as ->.
Check the var_dump(), first it contains an array and then objects.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit please? Thank you

Comment: 2 reasons this won't work. 1) Missing `'` 2) The 0 index is an object, not an array.

Comment: agreed this will not work... @JonStirling